# How to create a private array and access it by the main method in java?

Tags: java

I want to create a class outside the public class but in the same file, and in that class I wanna create a private array which can only be accessed by creating object through the previous public class. I also wanna store data to that array through the public class.

Comment: cool, what did you try so far?

Comment: Is this a school assignment?

Comment: What do you mean by that "class outside the public class"?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to start learning java, this will save you from asking this kind of question next time. For the moment you can find how to achieve what you are asking for in the example bellow :

```
public class Learning {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Course course = new Course();
        List<String> materials = new ArrayList<>();
        materials.add("java basic courses");
        materials.add("OOP courses");
        
        // here we use setters to set course materials and notes
        course.setMaterials(materials);
        course.setNotes(new int[] {19,20});

        System.out.println("Display course materials");
        for (String material : course.getMaterials()) {
            System.out.println("Material : " + material);
        }

        System.out.println("Display Notes");
        for (int note : course.getNotes()) {
            System.out.println("Note : " + note);
        }
    }
}

class Course {

    private List<String> materials;
    private int[] notes;


    public List<String> getMaterials() {
        return materials;
    }

    public void setMaterials(List<String> materials) {
        this.materials = materials;
    }

    public int[] getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(int[] notes) {
        this.notes = notes;
    }
}
```